# What is the history and significance of the "dire" prefix to creatures?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming

Some animals in [Pathfinder bestiaries](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/monsterIndex.html) are prefixed with "dire".

Does this come from the wolf species *[Canis dirus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dire_wolf)*, an early edition monster/template or something else?

Where does this come from and what significance does it have to these enemies?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Monte Cook introduced the "dire" animals in D&D 3e, according to [this blog post](http://montecook.livejournal.com/216904.html):

> When we were developing 3E, we recognized that we needed animals that could serve as appropriate foes and allies for mid- and high-level characters to help druid and ranger abilities continue to be valuable. It was my idea to create "dire" versions of various animals, based on the [dire wolf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dire_wolf)/wolf dichotomy. (I know, it only makes sense in a D&D sort of way.)

Comment: Just to add linguistic background to this excellent answer, **dire** is derived from Latin **dirus** meaning *frightening* or *terrible*.

Comment: Note: The linked LiveJournal post has since been removed (clicking the link gives me the error message "This journal has been deleted and purged."), and the Wayback Machine doesn't have an archive of it. It looks like your answer and one [ENWorld forum post](https://www.enworld.org/threads/%E2%80%AAwhat-does-the-word-%E2%80%9Cdire%E2%80%9D%E2%80%AC-mean-to-you.670896/post-7940274) (in a thread about this very topic) are the only two places that this portion of the linked post seems to have been quoted.

Answer (score 31):

This is one of those things that Wizards of the Coast invented with the 3rd edition, though you're right that it's rooted in the real dire wolf.

In editions prior to 3e, there was the dire wolf, which was simply the larger, prehistoric version of a regular wolf. WotC decided, for some reason, that having more "dire" versions of animals was useful – perhaps for encounter variety, perhaps for the Summon spells – and extended this scheme to other animals. Rather that being simply larger, megafauna versions of their smaller cousins, the art direction put bone spurs and other "badass" indicators on them, setting the theme for the later proliferation of dire animals.

"Dire" means simply "serious" or "grave" – the dire wolf was larger and significantly more threatening than a modern wolf – but in regular English it's not a very productive adjectival prefix and it's dying out as a stand-alone word, appearing mostly in fixed phrases rather than being used creatively on its own merits. With the WotC expansion of dire animals, it took on the connotations of bigger, badder, spikier, and (arguably) vaguely unnatural versions of the standard animal and has become a productive prefix for creating new meaningful names when combined with almost any word, at least within the domain of D&D.

Answer (score -3):

I don't have any of my old monster manuals handy, but as an old school TTRPGer I'm pretty sure that dire versions of animals existed way before DnD 3e.  Direwolves, bears, and other assorted common animals have had a place in the tomes of RPG's for a very long time, and have spread to other media as well.  Best example being the Direwolves of the Starks in the Song of Ice and Fire saga (or Game of Thrones tv show for those that prefer it). I do not know how the term came to use, but would guess that it has something to do with how we associate the word dire in modern society.  IE someone in desperate trouble may be said to be in dire straights. Hence anything with the prefix dire, would be assumed to be more problematic a foe than it's standard non-dire counterpart.

Comment: Well, "dire wolves" is the common name for an extinct species of wolf. The term shows up in Google Ngram all the way back to the 1850s. But bears, etc.? I've been looking for a citation, but haven't found one older than thirteen years ago.

Comment: @KnytFyre could be remembering an encounter with something a DM he played with just made up themselves. It's a simple enough extrapolation, to go from wolf/dire wolf to bear/dire bear, that it's not unreasonable to suspect Monte Cook may not have been the first person ever to have that idea.